# javascript/codecademy - if statement runs twice as false before evaluating true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

So I'm very new, and I'm on a refresher course on Codecademy. Is something wrong with my logic here?

```
// Declare your variables here!
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {
  // Add your if/else statement here!
  if(hungry && foodHere){
      console.log("problem solved!");
      return true;
  }
  else {
      console.log("why are you even here?");
      return false;
  }
}
```

A function with no parameter intake checks for two true statements, which are global and predefined. When i save & run this script, the output is

```
why are you even here?
why are you even here?
problem solved!
```

Which says to me that it evaluated false twice (though it shouldn't), kept running, and finally evaluated true, allowing me to move on. Secondly, if I set either or both of my variables to false, it outputs... nothing. No evaluation, no output.

Is there a problem here I'm just not seeing, or a glitch in the Codecademy console? I'd assume it's slow to check the statements? I'd rather figure this out before I keep going.

Comment: it isn't called, it runs naturally. This is the entire code, keep in mind it's on codecademy.

Comment: or actually, i should say, the function is called immediately because it's setting the value of a variable.

Comment: I have yet to see that syntax... what would that mean is happening to the code? Why doesn't the variable set correctly the first time, and end up evaluating three times?? Also, not seeing that share & download button...

Comment: I promise you this is 100% of the code I've typed. I wouldn't have access to any behind-the-scenes code. I'd post the picture but I don't have enough site rep! Anyway I typed this, hit run, and got the results in the console. Perhaps this is an altered form of javascript they use?

Comment: Please read canon's comment. Post a link to the workspace.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-qDwp0/2/2?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the codecademy directions listed [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-qDwp0/2/2?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661):

> Create two variables, `hungry` and `foodHere`, and set them both equal to `true`. Inside the `eat` function, create an `if` statement that returns `true` only if both `hungry` and `foodHere` are true, and `false` otherwise. The function `eat` should take no input and `hungry` and `foodHere` should both be globals.

Essentially, codecademy took your snippet and ran `eat()` a couple times, changing the values of `hungry` and `foodHere` in order to ensure that `eat()` returned the appropriate value for the conditions specified in the directions.

You didn't do anything wrong. Your code works fine.